# How to import more nodes to Local Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, ibp-vscode-extension

Now I can start the Local Fabric env, but in doc I see import more nodes items

> You can import more nodes to an existing environment by connecting to
>   the environment, expand nodes and then click on + Import nodes.

I cant find the "+" button. so where can I find it ?

[this is my software interface]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9SeT.png

Comment: You probably can't add more nodes to the local fabric environment. You would need to create a new fabric environment (representing an external fabric) by importing a set of nodes that describe that external fabric first.

Comment: thank you ! so if I am running a local env on my computer  such as byfn.sh . how can I import it ? or can I build it just by json file ? I find some issues in doc but I dont know the detail ? do you know some examples  ?

address is here : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=IBMBlockchain.ibm-blockchain-platform

Comment: You need to craft the JSON file yourself to describe the external fabric such as BYFN.The information about how to build these JSON files can be found here https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/blockchain-vscode-extension#json-node-files